# ViewPager Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

my apps contains 3 fragments, the first appear a ListFragment populated from an external data base, the second appear a map and the thir for adding a report into the data base, this is my code:

MainActivity's code:

```
package info.androidhive.tabsswipe;

import info.androidhive.tabsswipe.adapter.TabsPagerAdapter;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "My interventions", "MAP", "My report" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

}
```

ListFragment's code:

```
package info.androidhive.tabsswipe;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class TopRatedFragment extends ListFragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_rated,
                container, false);

        return myFragmentView;

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    }
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> interventionsList;
    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
 // url to get all interventions list
    private static String url_all_interventions = "http://10.0.2.2/Scripts/liste_interventions.php";
    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

     // interventions JSONArray
    JSONArray interventions = null;
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        this.getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        interventionsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading interventions in Background Thread
        new LoadAllInterventions().execute();
    }
    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllInterventions extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading interventions. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONArray json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_interventions, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Interventions: ", json.toString());

            try {

                    // Getting Array of interventions
                    JSONArray interventions = json;

                    // looping through All interventions
                    for (int i = 0; i < interventions.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = interventions.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String  id = c.getString("id");
                        String name = c.getString("name");

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put("Int_id",   id);
                        map.put("Int_name", name);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        interventionsList.add(map);
                    }

            } catch (JSONException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            getActivity(), interventionsList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { "Int_id",
                                    "Int_name"},
                            new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                    Log.e("LIST", "setListAdapter is done");
                }
            });

        }

    }
    public void runOnUiThread(Runnable runnable) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

MoviesFragment's code:

```
package info.androidhive.tabsswipe;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MoviesFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movies,
                container, false);

        return myFragmentView;

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        Button ajout=(Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button1);
        ajout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              EditText code=(EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText1);
              EditText lib=(EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText2);
              EditText desc=(EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText3);
              EditText st=(EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText4);
              EditText act=(EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText5);
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitNetwork().build());
              StringBuffer adresse= new StringBuffer("http://10.0.2.2:8080/Scripts/Create_Rapport.php?");
              adresse.append("code="+code.getText().toString());
              adresse.append("&lib="+lib.getText().toString());
              adresse.append("&desc="+desc.getText().toString());
              adresse.append("&state="+st.getText().toString());
            adresse.append("&action="+act.getText().toString());
              getPage(adresse.toString());
          }});
    }
    public void getPage(String adresse) {
    new Requete().execute(adresse);
}

    private class Requete extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> { 
        @Override 
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String response = ""; 
            for (String url : urls) { 
                DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url); 
                try { 
                    HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                } 
                catch (Exception e) { 
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                } 
            } 
            return response;
        } 
    }    
}
```

JSONParser's code:

```
package info.androidhive.tabsswipe;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONArray jArr = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONArray makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON array
        try {
            jArr = new JSONArray(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jArr;

    }
}
```

TabsViewPager class's code:

```
package info.androidhive.tabsswipe.adapter;

import info.androidhive.tabsswipe.GamesFragment;
import info.androidhive.tabsswipe.MoviesFragment;
import info.androidhive.tabsswipe.TopRatedFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            // Top Rated fragment activity
            return new TopRatedFragment();
        case 1:
            // Games fragment activity
            return new GamesFragment();
        case 2:
            // Movies fragment activity
            return new MoviesFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return 3;
    }

}
```

and this is the 3rd fragment's code:

```
package info.androidhive.tabsswipe;

import info.androidhive.tabsswipe.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class GamesFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_games, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Also this is movies_fragment layout's code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#99E7E5"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCreateRapport"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Créer Rapport" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:text="Nom de l'intervention"
        android:textSize="17dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:text="Etat"
        android:textSize="17dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:text="Description"
        android:textSize="17dip" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputAction"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/inputState"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:ems="10"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:text="Action corrective"
        android:textSize="17dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:text="Date"
        android:textSize="17dip" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputState"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/inputName"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:ems="10"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputDesc"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/inputAction"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:ems="10"
        android:singleLine="true" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputDate"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/inputDesc"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:ems="10"
        android:singleLine="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When i run the application, the first fragment don't appear the List from the DB, when i swipe to an other fragment, the application close and this which appear in the LogCat:

```
I/Choreographer(1708): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-26 21:54:30.778: 
D/All Interventions:(1708): [{"id":"2","name":"request 2"},{"id":"1","name":"request 1"}]
10-26 21:54:44.788: 
I/Choreographer(1708): Skipped 60 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-26 21:54:48.671: 
D/AndroidRuntime(1708): Shutting down VM
10-26 21:54:48.671: 
W/dalvikvm(1708): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
10-26 21:54:48.948: 
E/AndroidRuntime(1708): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-26 21:54:48.948: 
E/AndroidRuntime(1708): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-26 21:54:48.948: 
E/AndroidRuntime(1708):     at info.androidhive.tabsswipe.MoviesFragment.onActivityCreated(MoviesFragment.java:41)
10-26 21:54:48.948: 
E/AndroidRuntime(1708):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1486)
10-26 21:54:48.948: 
E/AndroidRuntime(1708):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
10-26 21:54:48.948: 
E/AndroidRuntime(1708):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
10-26 21:54:48.948: 
E/AndroidRuntime(1708):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
10-26 21:54:48.948: 
E/AndroidRuntime(1708):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
10-26 21:54:48.948: 
E/AndroidRuntime(1708):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
10-26 21:54:48.948: 
E/AndroidRuntime(1708):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
10-26 21:54:48.948: 
E/AndroidRuntime(1708):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
10-26 21:54:48.948: 
E/AndroidRuntime(1708):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:550)
10-26 21:54:48.948: 
E/AndroidRuntime(1708):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:509)
10-26 21:54:48.948: 
E/AndroidRuntime(1708):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:490)
10-26 21:54:48.948: 
E/AndroidRuntime(1708):     at info.androidhive.tabsswipe.MainActivity.onTabSelected(MainActivity.java:70)
10-26 21:54:48.948: 
E/AndroidRuntime(1708):     at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.selectTab(ActionBarImpl.java:579)
10-26 21:54:48.948: 
E/AndroidRuntime(1708):     at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl$TabImpl.select(ActionBarImpl.java:1081)
10-26 21:54:48.948: 
E/AndroidRuntime(1708):     at com.android.internal.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView$TabClickListener.onClick(ScrollingTabContainerView.java:519)
10-26 21:54:48.948: 
E/AndroidRuntime(1708):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
10-26 21:54:48.948: 
E/AndroidRuntime(1708):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
10-26 21:54:48.948: 
E/AndroidRuntime(1708):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
10-26 21:54:48.948: 
E/AndroidRuntime(1708):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-26 21:54:48.948: 
E/AndroidRuntime(1708):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-26 21:54:48.948: 
E/AndroidRuntime(1708):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-26 21:54:48.948: 
E/AndroidRuntime(1708):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-26 21:54:48.948: 
E/AndroidRuntime(1708):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-26 21:54:48.948: 
E/AndroidRuntime(1708):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-26 21:54:48.948: 
E/AndroidRuntime(1708):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-26 21:54:48.948: 
E/AndroidRuntime(1708):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any ideas please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your layout **movies_fragment.xml**, you button is given the id btnCreateRapport but in your MoviesFragment code you has used R.id.button1 in line 40. Since such button doesn't exist null pointer exception has occurred. Change your code to

```
Button ajout=(Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnCreateRapport);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your layout it's called `movies_layout` or `layout_movies`?

In your fragment you're setting it like `fragment_movies` and the file it's called `movies_fragment`.